# flask-login using UserMixin - no 'id' attribute error despite being implemented

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have been trying to use flask-login for authentication in my flask app. While trying to implement the **user_loader** like this:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.get_id(id)
```

i get the error

> **NotImplementedError: No `id` attribute - override `get_id`**

My User class is defined like this:

```
class User(Base, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(70), unique=True)
    userName = Column(String(40), unique=True)
    password = Column(String(150))

    #def get_id(self):
    #    return (self.id)
```

i tried overriding the get_id method, as you can see in the User class. It just got me the error

> **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'**

What am i missing? Why is the id attribute not found?

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly implementing a getter for the `id` variable in your override, but I think that you are misinterpreting how to use the function in the code to load a user by id. In your overridden function, `get_id` takes in no parameters besides `self`, because the function simply returns the id of a user. However you are trying to use this as a function to load a user from their id. The reason we are getting this specific error is because by calling `User.get_id(id)`, you are calling `get_id` with `self=id` and since `id` is a `str`, we get the `AttributeError` from trying to get the `id` property of `id`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `get` instead of `get_id` (as shown in [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins)).
This way the returned value is an instance of `User` with the desired `id`

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```